# JSF submitButton that renders on datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, datatable

This is my JSF(2.2) page :

```
<h:form>
<p>
    Hiker-name
</p>
<p>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="smenu">
        <f:ajax render="hikerActivities"/> 
        <c:forEach items="#{hikerPresenter.hikers}" var="hiker">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{hiker.hikerId}" itemLabel="#{hiker.hikerName}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <h:commandButton id="submitHiker" value="Submit" action="#{hikerPresenter.getHikerActivities(hiker.hikerId)}">
        <f:ajax execute="smenu" render="hikerActivities"/> 
    </h:commandButton>
</p>
<p>
    <h:dataTable id="hikerActivities"  var="hikerActivity" border="1">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header" >Trip-date</f:facet>
                #{hikerActivity.tripDate}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Trip-fare</f:facet>
                #{hikerActivity.tripFare}
        </h:column>                
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Trip-duration</f:facet>
                #{hikerActivity.tripDuration}
        </h:column>                
    </h:dataTable>
</p>
```

I want that with a click on the command button, my MBean's method get called with the hikerId from the selected item and gets render on the datatable.

this is my MBean :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HikerPresenter {
    @EJB
    private HikerControllerLocal hikerController;

    public HikerPresenter() {
    }

    public List<HikerAccessDTO> getHikers(){
        return hikerController.getHikers();
    }

    public List<HikerActivityDTO> getHikerActivities(long hikerId){
        System.out.println("Get Hiker Activities Called");
        List<HikerActivityDTO> l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(new HikerActivityDTO(new Date(1417150800000L), "Montréal", "Valleyfield", "Amine", 22, 45));
        l.add(new HikerActivityDTO(new Date(1417160800000L), "Montréal", "Québec", "Farida", 33, 44));
        l.add(new HikerActivityDTO(new Date(1417170800000L), "Montréal", "Alloha", "dsdsd", 12, 2332));
        return l;
    }
}
```

I suppose that I call the MBean method getHikerActivities on the wrong place because it doesn't even System.out.
What am-I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**1:**
use `f:selectItems` instead of `f:selectItem`

**2:**
your table missed the value attribute like `value="hikerPresenter.hikers"`

**3:**
You must set the value attribute of `h:selectOneMenu` to set `hikerId` into the bean, so its not necessary to send it as parameter in the method `getHikerActivities`

Comment: I prefert not to set a attribute in my MBeans. I what to pass the hikerId from the selectItem to the datatable then with the id call the MBean method to get the results

Comment: Its not possible to send the hikerId this way.. you must set the value selected in the list to the bean and used it.